# Calculate limit in probability sense, show it by definition $X_n \rightarrow_P X$

Tags: statistics, probability-limit-theorems

Assume we have a sequence of IID r.v.s $X_1, X_2,...,X_n ∼ N(−1, 2^2)$. Calculate the limit in
the Probability sense:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n}{X_1^2+X_2^2+...+X_n^2}$$

What I did:

So for first, I inversed the limit and separated it by parts $\rightarrow$ $\frac{X_1^2}{n}+\frac{X_2^2}{n}+...+\frac{X_n^2}{n}$

Then as r.v.s are IID, $E[X_1] = E[X_2] = ... = E[X_n] = -1$
$$E[X_1^2] = E[X_2^2] = ... = E[X_n^2] = \frac{X_1^2}{n} = var(X_1) + (E[X_1])^2 = 4 + 1 = 5$$

$$\frac{X_1^2}{n}+\frac{X_2^2}{n}+...+\frac{X_n^2}{n} = 5 + 5 + ... + 5 = 5n$$
and after inverseing it back we get
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n}{X_1^2+X_2^2+...+X_n^2} = \frac{1}{5n} = 0$$

So we get $X=0$, and by definition it is $$P(|X_n - X| \ge \epsilon) = 0$$
$$|X_n| \ge \epsilon$$ but $X_n$ is centered at $X=-1$ so $P(|X_n + 1| \ge \epsilon) = 0$

I am not sure if this is correct, is there anything I have done wrong?

Comment: You cannot simply replace $X_i^2$ by its expectation. $X_i^2$ equals $5$ *on average*, but it is a random quantity that lies somewhere between $0$ and $+\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using SLLN you have that

$$\frac{\sum_iX_i^2}{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}\mathbb{E}[X^2]=4+1=5$$

thus your sequence converges a.s. to $1/5$ and thus it converges also in probability